# When and why does UEFI need to access the partition table?

Tags: uefi

I have a workstation with an `UEFI` firmware and a disk with a `GPT` type partition table. According to EFI Boot Manager, the the system is instructed to boot from UUID `7e169454-1df0-40bf-9c63-0f6b094c1e15`:

```
# efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000
Boot0000* debian        HD(1,GPT,7e169454-1df0-40bf-9c63-0f6b094c1e15,0x800,0xee000)/File(\EFI\debian\grubx64.efi)
#
```

`7e169454-1df0-40bf-9c63-0f6b094c1e15` is the first partition of the `/dev/sdb` disk with `FAT32` file system:

```
# blkid /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: UUID="DA79-BCEA" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="7e169454-1df0-40bf-9c63-0f6b094c1e15"
#
```

According to [this UEFI guide](https://www.happyassassin.net/posts/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/), the UEFI spec requires, that UEFI is able to read the (`GPT`) partition table. Is this needed only during installing/editing the EFI Boot Manager? As I understand, the `efibootmgr` adds the start sector and end sector of the partition to the EFI Boot Manager entry. For example, based on the example above, my EFI Boot Manager entry contains the `0x800`(`2048` in decimal) and `0xee000`(`974848` in decimal) which match with the start and end sectors shown by the `fdisk` which reads those from the `GPT`:

```
# fdisk /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.33.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): i
Partition number (1-4, default 4): 1

         Device: /dev/sdb1
          Start: 2048
            End: 976895
        Sectors: 974848
           Size: 476M
           Type: EFI System
      Type-UUID: C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
           UUID: 7E169454-1DF0-40BF-9C63-0F6B094C1E15
```

Does `UEFI` need the access to the partition table in order to populate the EFI Boot Manager with start and end sectors information?

Or maybe `UEFI` requires access to partition tables during each boot because it needs to find the partition matching the `UUID`? If I understand [this `UEFI` guide](https://blog.uncooperative.org/blog/2014/02/06/the-efi-system-partition/#fn:1) correctly, then during the boot-up `UEFI` will initialize every peripheral in no particular order until it finds a partition matching that `UUID`. So in my example, it would read the `7e169454-1df0-40bf-9c63-0f6b094c1e15` from the EFI Boot Manager and then go through each block device and read their GPT until the partition with `7e169454-1df0-40bf-9c63-0f6b094c1e15` is found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> According to this UEFI guide, the UEFI spec requires, that UEFI is able to read the (GPT) partition table.

This is a specification requirement, so it means that while a particular UEFI firmware implementation **may** support other partition table formats too, **every** UEFI implementation **must** also support GPT in order to be compliant with the specification. So, an UEFI implementation on PC hardware will generally also support classic MBR partitioning, at least enough to recognize it. Apple's UEFI implementation may also support Apple's own old partitioning scheme, Oracle/Sun UEFI may also understand Solaris VTOC disklabels, and so on.

> Is this needed only during installing/editing the EFI Boot Manager?

The EFI Boot Manager is built-in to the UEFI firmware. You don't "install" it, ever. With the `efibootmgr` command, you can edit its *parameters* which are stored in non-volatile memory (NVRAM) on the motherboard.

An UEFI firmware will need the capability to read a GPT partition table on every boot, unless the system has been installed using alternative partition table formats supported by that particular UEFI implementation.

The string `HD(1,GPT,7e169454-1df0-40bf-9c63-0f6b094c1e15,0x800,0xee000)` in `efibootmgr` output is not just any string: it is a concise human-readable representation of a [UEFI *hard drive media device path* data structure](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/2_4_Errata_A.pdf#G13.1012034). That data structure is how the data is actually stored in the NVRAM for the EFI Boot Manager.

[The UEFI specification says](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/2_4_Errata_A.pdf#G7.1001226) (emphasised and split into paragraphs by me):

> The boot manager must also support booting from a short-form device path that starts with the first element being a *hard drive media device path* (see Table77).  The boot manager must use the GUID or signature and partition number in the hard drive device path to match it to a device in the system.
>
> If the drive supports the GPT partitioning scheme the GUID in the *hard drive media device path* is compared with the `UniquePartitionGuid` field of the GUID Partition Entry (see Table18).  If the drive supports the PC-AT MBR scheme the signature in the *hard drive media device path* is compared with the `UniqueMBRSignature` in the Legacy Master Boot Record (see Table13).
>
> If a signature match is made, then the partition number must also be matched.  The hard drive device path can be appended to the matching hardware device path and normal boot behavior can then be used.  If more than one device matches the hard drive device path, the boot manager will pick one arbitrarily.  Thus the operating system must ensure the uniqueness of the signatures on hard drives to guarantee deterministic boot behavior.

So the matching by the partition's unique UUID is the primary mechanism. The start & end sector information is just there to provide redundancy: any UEFI implementation is free to use it, or to ignore it.

The UEFI firmware might use the start & end sector information for e.g. further checks that the NVRAM information and the disk contents match each other. It would also allow the firmware to try and find the ESP partition by location if the disk's partition table seems to be damaged, resulting in a system that can be more robust against data errors. Each UEFI firmware implementer can decide for themselves if they'll want to use this extra information or not, and if they do, what will their overall strategy be.

A security-minded UEFI implementation might stop the boot process and report an error for any discrepancy, while an implementation designed for maximum reliability might try all combinations of the redundant information before failing, to maximize the chances of working around a single error in either the NVRAM or the partition table. A minimalist UEFI implementation might just stop with an error message if it fails to find a matching signature and completely ignore the extra information.

If you want to understand UEFI and its capabilities better, you should try using an UEFI shell. Some UEFI implementations (by e.g. Intel or Phoenix) have it as built-in; others (by AMI) have a specific option to run a `shellx64.efi` file if one is added to the root of your ESP (EFI System Partition). If all else fails, you can always place the `.efi` file of the shell onto your ESP and use `efibootmgr` to configure it as an additional boot menu item in EFI Boot Manager.

At the time of this writing, the newest pre-compiled version of UEFI shell available from the TianoCore project seems to be at:
https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/releases/download/edk2-stable201911/ShellBinPkg.zip